# Save PDF to location to folder on save

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-location

I've been searching for something I thought would be simple to find.

I have a form that takes the input fields and places the values on to a fillable PDF.

```
PDFDocument template = new PDFDocument(Server.MapPath("~/Forms/OfferSheet.pdf"));

template.Form.Fields["Seller"].Value = litName.Text;
template.Form.Fields["Address"].Value = litAddress.Text;
template.Form.Fields["Email"].Value = litEmailAddress.Text;
template.Form.Fields["Phone"].Value = string.Format("({0}) {1}-{2}", phone.Substring(0, 3), phone.Substring(3, 3), phone.Substring(6, 4));
template.Form.Fields["ProjectedFutureSale"].Value = string.Format("{0:n}", offer.FutureSalesPrice);
template.Form.Fields["PurchaseLoan"].Value = string.Format("{0:n}", offer.PurchasingLoanTitleClosing);
template.Form.Fields["Remodeling"].Value = string.Format("{0:n}", offer.Remodeling);
template.Form.Fields["Utilities"].Value = string.Format("{0:n}", offer.Utilities * 6);
template.Form.Fields["HOADues"].Value = string.Format("{0:n}", offer.HOADues / 2);
template.Form.Fields["Insurance"].Value = string.Format("{0:n}", offer.Insurance / 2);
template.Form.Fields["Taxes"].Value = string.Format("{0:n}", offer.Taxes / 2);
template.Form.Fields["LoanInterestCarry"].Value = string.Format("{0:n}", offer.LoanInterestCarry);
template.Form.Fields["InspectionRepairs"].Value = string.Format("{0:n}", offer.InspectionRepairs);
template.Form.Fields["SaleTitleClosingFees"].Value = string.Format("{0:n}", offer.SaleTitleClosingFees);
template.Form.Fields["RealEstateSalesCommission"].Value = string.Format("{0:n}", offer.SalesCommission);
template.Form.Fields["ProjectedProfit"].Value = string.Format("{0:n}", offer.ProjectedProfit);
template.Form.Fields["PurchasePrice"].Value = string.Format("{0:n}", offer.FinalOffer);
template.Form.Fields["ClosingDate"].Value = String.Format(new CultureInfo("en-US"), "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", offer.ClosingDate);
var date = DateTime.Now;
template.Form.Fields["SellerSig1"].Value = litName.Text;

template.FlattenFormFields();

using (MailMessage message = new MailMessage())
{
     message.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(new MemoryStream(template.GetPDFAsByteArray(), false), "PurchaseOffer.pdf"));
     message.Subject = "PurchaseOffer";
     message.Body = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FormEmail.Body"];

     message.To.Add(new MailAddress(lnkEmail.Text));

     new SmtpClient().Send(message);                
}

var fileName = prospect.FirstName + " " + prospect.LastName + DateTime.Now;
var rootPath = "~/Forms/Offers/";
var filePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(rootPath, fileName);
```

I need to not only email the PDF but to save the PDF to a file location so that the website admin can view the PDF. Any help is great.

Comment: you've already got the code to dump the generated pdf into an email. basically you need the same code, but dumping to a file output instead.

Comment: You cannot control from the server what happens on the client. Otherwise I would immediately start writing a website that replaces all files in `C:\Windows\System32`.

Comment: @Uwe - I'm pretty sure you know that isn't what I meant.

Comment: @JonHarding, "client side folder" and ASP.Net tag mean "file location on machine where browser opens a page". If you mean something else you probably should explain your terms better or stick with more traditional meanings of words.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot write to a client location.

But your admin could easily access the files on the server itself.
If not you can list files from this folder and provide a download option.

You should use the `File.WriteAllBytes` function to write your byte array to a local file.

```
var fileName = prospect.FirstName + " " + prospect.LastName + DateTime.Now;
var rootPath = "~/Forms/Offers/";
var filePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(rootPath, fileName);

File.WriteAllBytes(filePath, template.GetPDFAsByteArray());
```